# How to extend C: drive with the unallocated space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have 116GB unallocated space, which I want to use to expand my C drive (I only have only one physical hard drive). However, it seems that it's not an option for me, but why?

[image]

So what I want is to extend the `/dev/sda4`. My laptop has a dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu).

Comment: Why do you have unallocated space between all your partitions?

Comment: @Android -- they are most likely sector alignments

Comment: @ravery partition alignments

Comment: @heynnema - sector alignment for the start of the partition

Comment: @ravery you usually have the correct **general** idea, but slightly off on the specifics. Sectors don't get aligned. Partitions get aligned by starting partitions on **sector** boundaries.

Comment: @heynnema - let's call it semantics. the documentation I saw called it sector alignment of the partitions.

Comment: @ravery it's more than semantics. I'm trying to teach you the specifics that'll help you 1) better your understanding, and 2) make better answers. It's like your answer that says "you can't manipulate a mounted partition, it will cause file system errors" is blatantly incorrect. Although I agree that I wouldn't do it mounted, the fact is, that in some cases, you **can** move a mounted partition. Specifics.

Comment: @heynnema - and every time I have manipulated  a mounted partition is has corrupted, granted tools have gotten better but why take the chance?

Comment: @ravery As I said... I wouldn't do it mounted either. But again, I wanted you to understand the specifics of your statements. When answering, your statements need to be as close to 100% correct as possible.

Answer (score 3):

In short:

1. Backup everything
2. Boot an Ubuntu live CD/USB
3. Stop swapping on sda6
4. Move swap (sda6) and root (sda5) to the end of the unallocated space
5. Boot Windows
6. Resize the C drive (sda4)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @heynnema it the same as I said

Comment: @ravery Same steps, but linear (i.e. in order), so it's much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you can't manipulate a mounted partition, it will cause file system errors.

if you click on the swap partition, the pull down menu will let you  turn swap off. then you can move it to the end of the free space. then turn swap back on.

but you will need to boot from a LiveCD or other source in order to move the  linux root partition. then extend the windows drive from within windows. note: moving the root partition could cause boot issues for linux.

A better method is to move swap as described above, then make a partition formatted ntfs. windows will see it as a second drive.

Comment: The problem is that my hard drive is 500GB, but `/dev/sda4` only takes aprrox 300GB.

Comment: Actually ext4 does allow growing the partition on the fly... It's of course more secure to do it from a live system when it is not mounted, you're right there. And you should always have a backup for the rare case that something goes wrong.

Comment: oh, you want to increase the windows space? the easiest would be to move the swap as described, then make a ntfs partition window will see it as another drive. from a Live CD it is possible to move all of the linux partitions but that may cause boot problems.

Comment: Oh, but I just see he wants to grow his Windows NTFS partition, which is on the left of the Ubuntu partition. Then of course he needs to move both the swap and Ubuntu partition from a live system.

Comment: So the bottom line would be: backup your data, shutdown the system, boot from a separate Live USB drive, move the Linux ext4 and swap partitions out of the way (which is a very lengthy process); then you can extend the C:-drive /dev/sda4, and hopefully the Linux system is still usable.

Comment: @ravery creating another NTFS partition is NOT the right solution.

Comment: @heynnema -- I told him how to move and extend, the extra partition is a second option and safer than moving linux root partition

Comment: @ravery there should be no problem moving the / partition. If you were manipulating the Windows partition, then you may have Windows boot issues. Your second option really isn't/shouldn't be an option at all.

Comment: @heynnema - moving linux root could cause boot issue. usually not but... and the second opition is as valid as first, it makes the space usable to windows

Comment: @ravery **accessible** to Windows, yes, but not for Windows app installs, or Windows updates, or hibernation/page files, etc.

Comment: @heynnema there is not restriction on adding swap to a second drive and/or installing to a second drive. windows default is to use some space on all drives for swap